# how to use __year and __in in the same query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

So here's what I'm trying to do.
I've a list with years inside, for instance `years = [2002, 2003, 2004]`
and I've a `SomethingModel` with a `DateField`

I want to do a query that will return me all the objects that belongs to that year:

I known this work:

```
 SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__year=2003) 
 SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__in=[list with dates])
```

So I've tried this:

```
SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__year__in=years)
```

but this return me this error:

```
FieldError: Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?
```

Does anyone has any idea how to do this? In a direct way..

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't,  if you look at [the queryset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets)

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005)
```

becomes the SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE pub_date BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-12-31 23:59:59.999999';
```

So you can't mix __in and __date conceptually.  You can't mix suffixes anyway since the first "suffix" will be interpreted as a non-existent relationship.

You'll need to use a less than filter and a greater than filter or, if the list isn't contiguous, an extra where field, something like:

```
SomethingModel.objects.extra(where=["YEAR(date) IN (" + ",".join([str(x) for x in [2003, 2008, 2010]]) + ")"])
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted! Thanks :) Although it only works with the square parentesis: SomethingModel.objects.extra(where=["YEAR(date) IN (2002, 2006)"])

Comment: although it doesn't work if I try to replace (2002, 2006, 2009) to years. it seems it doesn't accept a variable name..

Comment: of course, I was just saying because it may be helpful for other persons! thank you, it works :)

Comment: perhaps this would also work: Entry.objects.extra(where=['headline=%s'], params=['Lennon'])
I was going to try this before you updated your answer :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__year=[year for year in years])
```

Comment: I had already tried that.. gives the same error since it's not an int

Answer (score 0):

If your list of years are always consecutive you can do

```
SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__year__gte=years[0], date__year__lte=years[-1])
```

Comment: no, the list of years is chosen by the user. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
SomethingModel.objects.filter(date__range=(date_1, date_2)