# Filtering data by month from a date field Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need to write a query that returns all objects in a month list. Month will be calculated from a date field i.e (2012-10-21 or 2011-04-14). When i am doing it for a single month its working fine
`**Table.objects.filter(ad_date__month=month)**`. assume month = 05

But when i am trying to do it in a list of months its not working.
`**Table.objects.filter(ad_date__month__in=month_list)**`. assume month_list = [11, 03, 01, 10]

I am getting this error:

```
"Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'month' for the lookup type?"
```

It seems Django considers it as a join operation.

Please suggest, i am stuck in this problem from last 2 days.

Comment: Just as a quick point, you can just call Table.objects.filter(...), you don't need to call .all() on the queryset first

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440219/how-to-use-year-and-in-in-the-same-query

Comment: @aamir adnan: i had tried the link you have shared, but its not working for me.

Comment: query_set = Table.objects.all().filter( Table1__ad_date__month__in=month_list)                                        
                              query_set = Table.objects.extra(where=["MONTH(table1__ad_date) IN (" + ",".join([str(x) for x in month_list]) + ")"])

this is exactly what i am doing. Here "table1" is another model which has the foreign key in "table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is doable using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

The following comprehension will create a Q object for every month in your `month_list`.

```
(Q(ad_date__month=month) for month in month_list)
```

All on one line this is now

```
Table.objects.filter(*(Q(ad_date__month=month) for month in month_list))
```

EDIT:

You can use the reduce function to "or" all these Q objects together

```
import operator
q_objects = (Q(ad_date__month=month) for month in month_list)
Table.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_objects))
```

Comment: I think you want `Q()|Q()` instead of `and`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is not very good but it will work.

```
from itertools import chain

result_list = []
for mm in month_list:
    this_query = Table.objects.filter(ad_date__month=mm)
    result_list = chain(result_list, this_query)
```